# Riding Cannondale Synapse on Paris-Roubaix terrain?

Tags: road-bike, cannondale

I've test ridden the Synapse Sora 7 and love it! Going to buy it! But i've one concern. 
I'd like to know if I can ride my Synapse on the same terrain as seen along the Paris-Roubaix? 
I've seen the Cannondale Synapse in action at the Paris-Roubaix with Ruben Zepuntke. But his bike is a special model, mine isn't. 
So can my 2015 Cannondale Synapse Sora 7 withstand a normal Paris-Roubaix route? 
My LBS clerk responded with "i'm not sure" when I asked that question.

Comment: The real question is how hard will you ride it? Then, as @John says [can the rider withstand it](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/34378/8273)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bike can withstand it.  The question remains whether the ride can withstand it.  As for the bike, there are a handful of issues that are more likely to arise on such rides:

- Filthy chain and gears.  Clean after each dirty ride.  Lube chain regularly.  Replace chain every one or two thousand miles, in accordance with a chain wear gauge.
- Pinch flats.  You want low pressure in the tyres for comfort, but not so low that they pinch when running over gaps, ruts, and stones.  Use higher-volume tires such as 28mm ("28c") ones, but try them out in the store to make sure they fit your particular bike.
- Eventually, blown spokes.  You will probably break a spoke if you ride on such terrain for thousands of kilometers.  This depends a lot on your weight and riding style.
- Random bits getting loose.  Check the bike after every long ride for loose fasteners.  Use Loc-tite where appropriate.

The above would apply to any performance-oriented bike to some degree.  A more expensive road bike like the professionals use is of little advantage--what you really need is a team mechanic who looks after all these issues every day.